# SQL SELECT - запрос из всех таблиц в базе

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, запрос

У меня имеется БД MS SQL с тысячей таблиц с именем формата "table1", "table2", ..., "table1000". Колонки в таблицах - одинаковые.

Необходимо как-то объединить таблицы в одну.

Я пытаюсь сделать это при помощи

```
SELECT названия_столбцов FROM X
```

где на месте `Х` нужно как-то перечислить названия всех таблиц, но не руками, а какой-то переменной/циклом/каким-то еще средством.

Comment: Задайте вопрос на русском языке

Comment: @PashaPash У меня имеется БД MS SQL с тысячей таблиц с именем формата "table1", "table2", ..., "table1000". Колонки в таблицах - одинаковые. Необходимо как-то объединить таблицы в одну. Я пытаюсь сделать это при помощи SELECT названия_столбцов FROM X, где на месте Х нужно как-то перечислить названия всех таблиц, но не руками, а какой-то переменной/циклом/каким-то еще средством.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT * FROM ?'
```

sp_MSforeachtable принимает параметром SQL, который надо выполнить, и подставляет имя таблицы в формате [schema].[Table].

Если нужно отфильтровать некоторые таблицы - можно добавить в этот SQL IF с проверкой на имя в `?`.

Если нужно выбирать данные не просто так, а виде одного сплошного результата -  то лучше до вызова `sp_MSforeachtable` создать временную таблицу и заменить SELECT на `INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT col1, col2 FROM ?`. И выбрать общий результат из #temptable по сразу после `sp_MSforeachtable`

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант (без временных таблиц) можно сгенерировать большой динамический запрос на основе метаданных:

```
declare @query varchar(max) = '';

select @query = @query + case @query when '' then '' else ' union all ' end + ' select id from ' + table_name  
from
(
    select distinct table_name 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where column_name in ('id')
) s

exec (@query)
```