# SELECT одинаковые поля со всех таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Все таблицы в базе имеют одинаковые поля. Такие таблицы будут постепенно добавлятся пользователями, поэтому вписать сразу в код все их названия невозможно, а править код каждый раз после добавления новой таблицы это не решение (это имелось в виду когда писал раньше что "названия таблиц неизвестны"). Нужно брать поля со всех таблиц, которые существуют на данный момент. Вопрос кажется тривиальный но ответ оказалось найти не просто. Пробовал и так:

```
$sql = "SELECT `myfield2` FROM * WHERE `myfield1` LIKE '$sometext%'";
```

и так

```
$sql = "SELECT `myfield2` FROM `mydbname`.* WHERE `myfield1` LIKE '$sometext%'";
```

но ничего не работает

Решил сделать вот так:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$alltables = $pdo->query("show tables");
$arrayOfTables = array();
foreach($alltables as $thistable) {
    $arrayOfTables[] = $thistable[0];
}
$i = 0;
$len = count($arrayOfTables);
$arrayForString = array();
foreach($arrayOfTables as $table) {
    if($i == $len-1) {
        $arrayForString[] = "SELECT `myfield2` FROM `".$table."` WHERE `myfield1` LIKE '$sometext%'";
    } else {
        $arrayForString[] = "SELECT `myfield2` FROM `".$table."` WHERE `myfield1` LIKE '$sometext%' UNION ";
    }
    $i++;
}
$sqlString = implode(',',$arrayForString);
$sql = str_replace(',SELECT','SELECT',$sqlString);
foreach($pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    echo $row['myfield2'];
}
```

Это работает но есть что то проще / лучше / правильнее ?

ps. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444026/sql-select-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5) кажется только для MS SQL

Comment: Для извлечения списка таблиц можете использовать `information_schema`: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables`. Просто удивительно что сами этого не нашли. Только какое в вашей ситуации принципиальное отличие от `SHOW TABLES` даже не знаю. Больше знаков разве что.

Comment: *не спрашивайте почему в разных таблицах* - и все-таки спрошу: а почему так? Почему вы не знаете названия таблиц? Зачем это все? Может стоит сделать небольшие переделки и задача будет решаться очень просто? Можно, например, над вашими таблицами использовать [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) или [объединенную таблицу](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html), тогда выборка будет только над одной таблицей (визуально, на деле mysql за вас будет пробегать по этим таблицам)

Comment: @banme, об `information_schema` я читал но так и не понял как пользоваться

Comment: information_schema - это специальная база данных, которая хранит информацию обо всех других базах на сервере: их названия, их таблицы и поля в таблицах, прочее. Вся эта информация представлена в таких же таблицах, как и в наших обычных базах. И доступна с помощью таких же SQL запросов.

Comment: @stckvrw, а если вместо добавления новой таблицы пользователи будут использовать только одну? Добавили в существующую два поля: `user_id` и `table_name`, сделали по этим двум полям уникальный ключ и тогда вместо выборки по нескольким таблицам будем искать только в одной. Выборка по данным `user_id;table_name` будет равнозначна выборке из соответствующей таблицы. Еще как вариант - использовать тот же view и при создании таблицы пользователем добавлять в него данную таблицу

Comment: Решили напугать десятками тысяч записей? И кого? Базу данных? А ещё у баз данных бывает такой инструмент как partitioning: http://habrahabr.ru/post/66151/

Comment: @stckvrw, у нас в приложении десятки и сотни миллионов записей - и ничего, работает все

Comment: Я имел в виду не в базе вообще, а в таблице одной если много записей, не лучше ли их разделить на отдельные таблицы, чтобы не "перегружать" одну ?

Comment: Вообще-то тоже имеется в виду одна таблица с миллионом записей без каких-либо проблем. Но раз Вам угодно,можете перегружать базу миллионом таблиц. Никто же не настаивает, даже помогли как могли.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте view на union всех таблиц. И выборку уже делайте из одной view.

**UPD**

> Такие таблицы будут постепенно добавлятся пользователями

Именно это не верное решение.
Нельзя менять структуру БД во время работы приложения. Попробуйте использовать стандартные средства БД.

Comment: таблицы заранее неизвестны, т.е. создание view вместо прямого select'a ничего по сути не меняет. Почему таблицы неизвестны - вопрос к ТС, возможно, ему надо просто пересмотреть используемый подход, тогда, возможно, и view не нужен будет

Comment: Это потенциально опасно и неправильно выбирать все из всего. Все же лучше узнать название таблиц.  В конце концов можно сделать преднастройку перед обращением к БД и на этом этапе создать view. И, далее, в приложении обращаться к ней.

Comment: Да ваще полностью программу составить, чего уж там мелочиться с небольшими примерами.

Comment: @ВячеславЖуравлев, в каком смысле _"нельзя менять структуру БД во время работы приложения"_ ?

Comment: Правда что ли нельзя? Сколько раз менял и работает, меняется. Причем стандартными средствами БД. Других-то нет.

Comment: @banme нельзя не потому что BD это запрещает, а потому что это усложняет жизнь в случае сколько нибудь серьезного приложения

Comment: Не учите меня жить, лучше помогите материально:)

Comment: @talex, я лично пока не понимаю каким образом частое использование `CREATE TABLE` усложняет жизнь, обьясните, мне и дальше интересно как лучше / правильнее

Comment: @stckvrw Ну например это приводит к тому что sql придеться генерировать на лету. Что не дает нормально работать кешу запросов. Актуальной статистики по таким таблицам тоже не будет. Правильнее в данном случае будет иметь одну таблицу. И использовать партиционирование если это надо и поддерживается вашей RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

По вашей логике:

1. Вытягиваем названия таблиц из sql. show table.
2. Переводим  в массив названий.
3. Подставляем в текст запроса. будет чтото типа

Итерация перебора массива:

```
$q =  $q .'union select * from'.$table_name.'where blablabla';
(Первое union убираем)
```

4. Выполняем запрос. Не в цикле уже а с полным текстом.

Answer (score -1):

> в таблице одной если много записей, не лучше ли их разделить на отдельные таблицы, чтобы не "перегружать" одну ?

## Нет, не лучше.

А сто крат хуже. И данный вопрос - это одна из самых простых проблем, которые возникают из этого архитектурного промаха. Дальше будет только хуже, причем некоторые проблемы не будут решаться вообще.

Поэтому надо не "выбирать одинаковые поля с разных таблиц", а сделать одну таблицу, и выбирать из неё обычным порядком.